# Vuejs Passing Data from child to parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Need some help. I have a component

```
<BasicFilter></BasicFilter>
```

with a select

```
<select @change="$emit('onSortName', $event)">
<option value="asc"> A..Z</option><option value="desc"></select>
```

and want to pass the selected value to a function in parent:

```
onSortName(event) {
  if (event.target.value == 'desc') {
    do something
  }
}
```

How to pass the `event.target.value` to the function in the parent?

Answer (score 1):

In child you emit event with data you want to send to parent:

```
<select @change="$emit('onSortName', data)">
```

in parent template you listen to event:

```
<BasicFilter @onSortName="onSortName"></BasicFilter>
```

method to do something on event from child

```
methods: {
  onSortName(val) {
    if (val == 'desc') {
      //do something
    }
  }
}
```